# Copy emacs shell input list to a buffer or file

Tags: emacs, elisp

I have an emacs shell buffer and would like to save each command that I have input as a new line of text in a new temporary buffer.

My shell history is something like:

```
% echo 1
% echo 2
```

I have found `comint-dynamic-list-input-ring` which contains the commands but it's in a reverse-sorted table like this

```
echo2       echo1
```

I need a forward-sorted chronological list, ideally in a temporary buffer so I can edit the buffer and save to a `.bash` file or what have you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should set `comint-input-ring-file-name` and use `comint-write-input-ring` to save your commands:

```
(defun my-shell-buffers ()
  "Return the list of buffers with non-nil `comint-input-ring'."
  (let (ret)
    (dolist (b (buffer-list) ret)
      (with-current-buffer b
        (when comint-input-ring
          (push (buffer-name b) ret))))))
(defun my-edit-history (comint-buffer history-file)
  (interactive
   (list (completing-read "Comint buffer: "
                          (or (my-shell-buffers)
                              (error "No shell buffers"))
                          nil t nil nil
                          (and comint-input-ring (buffer-name)))
         (read-file-name "History file name: ")))
  (with-current-buffer comint-buffer
    (let ((comint-input-ring-file-name history-file))
      (comint-write-input-ring)
      (find-file comint-input-ring-file-name))))
```

Comment: Excellent, I can create a little custom function to prompt for a file name, save the input ring, then find that file in a buffer for editing.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks so much to @sds

Just for the record, my own latest version is:

```
(defun write-input-ring (filename)
  "Write shell input to FILENAME then visit FILENAME."
  (interactive "F")
  (let ((comint-input-ring-file-name filename))
    (comint-write-input-ring))

  (if (file-readable-p filename)
      ;; If the input ring was saved to a file, visit that file
      (find-file filename)
    ;; Else report that no input was saved
    (message "This buffer has no shell history.")))
```

Comment: what do you expect it to do when you call it in a non-`comint` buffer?

Comment: I thought that maybe it could `(message "This buffer has no shell history") `. However, I like the current solution and it works fine so I'm only curious as to how it could be done.  Thanks so much for pointing out the way forward yesterday.

Comment: Wow thanks. I think there's a typo in the `(when c` line. Maybe this should be `(when comint-input-ring `. Answers like this are the best way for people new to elisp to learn.